# Will a micro-SIM intended for an iPhone 4 work in a Nokia Lumia 800?

Tags: nokia-lumia-800

I've recently got a Nokia Lumia 800 without any mobile plan (i.e. *just* the phone).

I'd like to get a pay-as-you-go SIM card for it, but it needs a "micro-SIM", and the only "SIM only" plans I can find call it the "[micro SIM for iPhone](http://store.three.co.uk/SIM_Only/iPhone_Micro_SIM)" - I remember that when I was updating my last phone, the store I was in implied that there were standard SIMs, micro-SIMs and iPhone-SIMs - was this my misunderstanding, and should I be fine with an "iPhone" Micro-SIM, or do I need to get something more specific?

Comment: You can go to one of those privately-owned highstreet shops or market stalls that sell mobile phone stuff (like covers) and ask them if they can make your SIM into a micro-SIM.  They may have one of these punches - http://daveburrows.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/lupo.jpg  That's what I did, as Orange sent me the wrong size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The micro sim used in an iPhone is a standard one. It will work. You can also turn any standard sim into a micro sim.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LebM5624Zfk

Comment: I printed out a template from here http://amjath.com/2010/08/how-to-make-a-micro-sim-from-a-normal-sim.html works great in Nokia, HTC and Apple phones.

Comment: You can also get an adaptor so that you can use your new micro in an older phone. I got a pair for a couple of bucks.